# PostgreSQL: column "featured" of relation "photos_photo" does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I am using Postgres with Django, but when I try to upload a photo, I get the following error: `column "featured" of relation "photos_photo" does not exist`. However, the field is in fact in my model and the migrations have been made properly.

When I go into dbshell, the column isn't displayed. Additionally, `private` and `likers` aren't there either. Any ideas how to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

***models.py:***

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", default=1, null=False, blank=False)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    likers = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='Likers', blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='user/photos/', null=False, blank=False)
    private = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, blank=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
```

***postgres table:***

```
Column    |           Type           |                         Modifiers                         | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id          | integer                  | not null default nextval('photos_photo_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 title       | character varying(30)    |                                                           | extended |              | 
 description | text                     |                                                           | extended |              | 
 image       | character varying(100)   |                                                           | extended |              | 
 slug        | character varying(50)    | not null                                                  | extended |              | 
 active      | boolean                  | not null                                                  | plain    |              | 
 timestamp   | timestamp with time zone | not null                                                  | plain    |              | 
 category_id | integer                  |                                                           | plain    |              | 
 creator_id  | integer                  | not null
```

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Comment: Have you added these fields or changed their names since you ran `syncdb` or `migrate`?

Comment: @Hevlastka Django 1.8

Comment: @miyamoto Nothing has been altered since I ran `migrate`. When I do migrate, the database tells me there are no migrations to be made.

Comment: @jape Try running `makemigrations` before running migrate, this will force Django to look for changes between the models and the database and create a new migration from them.

Comment: @Hevlastka I've tried that, and it says "no changes detected".

Comment: Did you use [`--fake`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake) flag on the `migrate` call? That could lead to this situation.